# Special character codes are displayed in the Terminal for diacritics when connecting to an Ubuntu Server

Tags: terminal, ssh, unix, unicode, utf-8

When I connect to an Ubuntu Server (ssh) and I try to see some text in the Terminal form the remote server, I get character codes instead of the appropriate text with diacritics.

for example for a `git log` on the server I get:

```
Author: Ionic<C4><83> Biz<C4><83>u <bizauionica@...>
```

instead of:

```
Author: Ionică Bizău <bizauionica@...>
```

When I do `git log` on my local machine in the Terminal, I get the correct diacritics.

I have no idea in which category this issue falls:

- Terminal
- bash
- ssh
- Ubuntu
- git

I initially asked Ubuntu for [this issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/419312/ubuntu-server-terminal-displays-character-codes-for-diacritics-c483-inste) but they redirected me here.

Any ideas?

Comment: Terminal is showing the UTF-8 bytes in hex for the non-ascii character, probably some preference setting needs adjustment.

Comment: What does `locale` print on the server, or have you tried running `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8`?

Comment: On the Ubuntu server (seen through SSH): `
LANG=en_US.UTF-8 
LANGUAGE= 
LC_CTYPE=UTF-8 
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8" 
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8" 
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8" 
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8" 
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8" 
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8" 
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8" 
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8" 
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8" 
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8" 
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8" 
LC_ALL= 
`

Comment: And on my Mac: `
LANG= 
LC_COLLATE="C" 
LC_CTYPE="UTF-8" 
LC_MESSAGES="C" 
LC_MONETARY="C" 
LC_NUMERIC="C" 
LC_TIME="C" 
LC_ALL= 
`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `LC_ALL` variable having an empty value was causing the problem.

So the solution of this problem can be found on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165108/in-osx-lion-lang-is-not-set-to-utf8-how-fix):

On mac, the `LC_ALL` variable is not set by default. So writing:

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

in your `~/.bash_profile` fixes the problem. I assume that You have a default SSH config that has `LC_*` in the `SendEnv` configuration.